# Power Automate convert csv file to EML format

Tags: azure, power-automate

I am trying to create a flow in Power Automate which reads a csv file from azure blob and
convert it to EML format as defined by RFC 2822 then attach that to email and send to a recipient.

The part that I am stuck at is creating the eml wrapper once I read the content of the file

Is there any action in power automate flow that can do this?

[image]

Comment: Why don’t you just attach it within the email itself? You just pass the content into the Send an email (v2) step along with a name for the attachment.

Comment: the attachment is csv that i want to convert to eml format and then attach it to email and send it. The flow above  the attachment is still in csv format

Comment: My question is why do you want it in EML format?

Comment: An example exists here ... https://github.com/FlexConfirmMail/Thunderbird/blob/master/sample.eml

Comment: @Skin eml format is requirement of a third party their system can only consume file in that format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do agree with @Skin, Alternatively, I would suggest you to Azure Logic apps and you can use below approach:

**`Design:`**

Here I taken CSV data directly, you can take it from Azure Blob storage:

[image]

JavaScript Code:

```
const rithcsv =workflowContext.actions.Compose.outputs;
const rows = rithcsv.trim().split('\n').map(row => row.split(','));
const headers = rows.shift();
const data = rows.map(row => {
  const rithobj = {};
  headers.forEach((header, i) => rithobj[header] = row[i]);
  return rithobj;
});
const ritheml = `
${data.map(row => `${row.Test} ${row.Body} ${row.OtherField}`).join('\n')}
`;
return ritheml;
```

Then:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: perfect this works